# Polymerfire error pushing data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, polymer, polymerfire

I am creating a contract between two users and structuring my database as stated bellow. The problem is that I am having issues creating the contract with both users `user_id:true`. I am not sure if I am taking the right approach. I am following the firebase documentation and structuring the contract as recommended.

```
my-firebase
|
-contracts
  |- contract-id
    |- user_id: true
    |- user_id: true
    |- amount: 1000
    |- isactive: true
    |- started: 148314234733
```

I am creating the contract:

```
var contractDetails = {
 this.contractor:true,
 this.freelancer:true,
 amount: 1000,
 isactive: true,
 started: 'eee'
};
```

Comment: Are the user_ids different? Right now you have two of the same key which is not allowed in json.

Comment: yes both user_id's are different. The contract belong to 2 different users

Comment: You state that there is a problem, but what is the actual problem? Do you have an error message or some code?

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your use of `this`. If you are using ES6, you can use [computed properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

```
var contractDetails = {
  [this.contractor]: true,
  [this.freelancer]: true,
  amount: 1000,
  isactive: true
  started: this.timestamp
};
```

If you are not, you can do something like this, instead:

```
var contractDetails = {
  amount: 1000,
  isactive: true
  started: this.timestamp
};
contractDetails[this.contractor] = true;
contractDetails[this.freelancer] = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

How to query only the `"contract"` that are `"isactive"` for a `"user"`
- contract-id --) isactive: "true"_user.uid // Combine data to create a single 
- query --) order-by-child="[[queryHandler]]"

```
- contract-id --) add property `user_uid_contractor` bind to `user.uid`<br>

    -contracts
      |- contract-id
        |- user_uid_freelancer: user.uid
        |- user_uid_contractor: user.uid
        |- amount: 1000
        |- isactive: "true"_user.uid // Combine data to create a single query.
        |- started: 148314234733
```

Code Query Employee Contract

```
  <firebase-query
   app-name="vida"
   path="/contracts"
   data="{{mycontracts}}"
   order-by-child=""true_"[[queryHandler]]"
   equal-to="[[user.uid]]"></firebase-query>

       properties:{
       queryHandler // computed value that build the path
       }
```